# Привязка значений к выпадающему списку из QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qcombobox

Пожалуйста, подскажите,
есть `QComboBox`, 
в нём есть **`три`** раздела: "Боевик", "Военный", "Детектив".

Нужно привязать к этим разделам списки.

Подскажите, каким образом это можно осуществить?

---

**`Example of list:`**

```
#Боевик:
[
"Безумный Макс: Дорога ярости\n2015 г.\nIMDb: 8,1",
"Малыш на драйве\n2017 г.\nIMDb: 7,7",
"Мстители\n2012 г.\nIMDb: 8,1"
]

#Военный:
[
"Атака на Перл Харбор\n2011 г.\nIMDb: 6.8",
"Ярость\n2014 г.\nIMDb: 7.6",
"Спасти рядового Райана\n1998 г.\nIMDb: 8.6"
]

#Детектив:
[
"Зеленая миля\n1999 г.\nIMDb: 8.5",
"Начало\n2010 г.\nIMDb: 8.8",
"Престиж\n2006 г.\nIMDb: 8.5"
]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
import sys
from random   import choice
from PyQt5    import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from designUi import Ui_MainWindow

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, myList, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.myList = myList

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.ui.label,      0, 0) 
        grid.addWidget(self.ui.label_2,    1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.ui.comboBox,   2, 0) 
        grid.addWidget(self.label_3,       3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.ui.pushButton, 4, 0)         

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

        self.comboIndex = 0
        self.ui.comboBox.activated[int].connect(self.onActivatedText)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int) 
    def onActivatedText(self, index):
        self.comboIndex = index     

    def MyFunction(self):
        self.label_3.setText(choice(self.myList[self.comboIndex]))


myList = [
    ['Безумный Макс: Дорога ярости   2015 г. IMDb: 8,1',
    'Малыш на драйве ____________ 2017 г. IMDb: 7,7',
    'Мстители ___________________ 2012 г. IMDb: 8,1'],
    ['Атака на Перл Харбор __ 2011 г. IMDb: 6.8',
    'Ярость _______________ 2014 г. IMDb: 7.6',
    'Спасти рядового Райана  1998 г. IMDb: 8.6'],
    ['Зеленая миля   1999 г. IMDb: 8.5',
    'Начало ______ 2010 г. IMDb: 8.8',
    'Престиж _____ 2006 г. IMDb: 8.5']
]

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin(myList)
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

designUi.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 220)                        # 400
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 220))  # 400
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 220))  # 400
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icons8-Ios7-Cinema-Documentary.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setAccessibleName("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 151, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 111, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 121, 22))
        self.comboBox.setMaxVisibleItems(8)
        self.comboBox.setFrame(True)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Know You Better"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Помочь Вам выбрать фильм?!"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Нажмите на меня"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите жанр"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "Боевик"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Боевик"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Военный"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Детектив"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень круто!!! Но немного не то - в списке 3 элемента, а должен появляться лишь один (случайный).

Comment: Пробуйте, я обновил ответ

Comment: Магию ведь нельзя использовать вне Хогвартса........БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как называется виджет, в котором выводится текст?

Comment: 1. `self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel()`  2. `grid.addWidget(self.label_3,       3, 0)`  3. `self.label_3.setText(choice(self.myList[self.comboIndex]))`

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как Вы обращаетесь к НЕпроиндексированным спискам?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам принципиально нужно сделать программу с `QMessageBox`, то этот вариант, надеюсь, вам пойдет:

```
import sys
from films import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.ok.clicked.connect(self.message)

        self.a = [
            "Безумный Макс: Дорога ярости\n2015 г.\nIMDb: 8,1",
            "Малыш на драйве\n2017 г.\nIMDb: 7,7",
            "Мстители\n2012 г.\nIMDb: 8,1"
            ]

        self.b = [
            "Атака на Перл Харбор\n2011 г.\nIMDb: 6.8",
            "Ярость\n2014 г.\nIMDb: 7.6",
            "Спасти рядового Райана\n1998 г.\nIMDb: 8.6"
            ]

        self.c =  [
            "Зеленая миля\n1999 г.\nIMDb: 8.5",
            "Начало\n2010 г.\nIMDb: 8.8",
            "Престиж\n2006 г.\nIMDb: 8.5"
            ]
        self.index = self.ui.combo.currentIndex()

    def message(self):
        self.messageb = QtWidgets.QMessageBox ()
        self.messageb.setIcon (QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Information)
        self.messageb.setWindowTitle ("Рекомендую: ")

        if self.index == 0:
            self.messageb.setText (str (random.SystemRandom ().choice (self.a)))
        elif self.index == 1:
            self.messageb.setText (str (random.SystemRandom ().choice (self.b)))
        elif self.index == 2:
            self.messageb.setText (str (random.SystemRandom ().choice (self.c)))

        self.okButton = self.messageb.addButton ('Ок', QtWidgets.QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
        self.messageb.exec ()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = Window()
    application.show()
    sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

И файл `films.py` это QUI приложения:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'films.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.combo.setObjectName("combo")
        self.combo.addItem("")
        self.combo.addItem("")
        self.combo.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.combo, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ok.setObjectName("ok")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ok, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.combo.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Помочь выбрать фильм?"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите жанр:"))
        self.combo.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Боевик"))
        self.combo.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Военный"))
        self.combo.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Детектив"))
        self.ok.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подобрать фильм!"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То что нужно!!!!! БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!! При выводе QMessageBox появляются рандомные значения из ВСЕХ списков.Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли привязать списки[a,b,c] к конкретному разделу выпадающего меню (т.е. Боевик == а (только а), военный == b (только b) и т.д.)?

Comment: Я так и привязал с помощью условной конструкции. Сначала мы получаем индекс элемента, который активирован в QComboBox, их тут всего 3, значит индексы 0,1,2. Условная конструкция:
если индекс 0, то выбирай рандомное значение из списка а, если индекс 1, то из списка б и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать список привести к строке и записать ее в переменную, затем уже по нажатию на выпадающий список `QComboBox` производить изменение текста, например, в `QLabel` или же выводить текст в `QTextBrowser`

Comment: Смысл в том, что элементы списка будут рандомно выпадать в QMessageBox .... т.е. User выбирает жанр, нажимает на кнопку и  ему рандомно выпадает значение списка............ Интересное предложение, но думаю оно не очень подходит для данной программы.